# Multiline regex match in MariaDB/Mediawiki

Tags: sql, regex, mariadb, mediawiki, recursive-query

I am trying to match text (contained in a Mediawiki template) in multiple lines via the [Replace Text extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Replace_Text) in MW 1.31, server running MariaDB 10.3.22.

An example of the template is the following (other templates may exist on the same page):

```
{{WoodhouseENELnames
|Text=[[File:woodhouse_999.jpg|thumb|link={{filepath:woodhouse_999.jpg}}]]Αἰακός, ὁ, or say, son of Aegina.

<b class="b2">Of Aeacus</b>, adj.: Αἰάκειος.

<b class="b2">Descendant of Aeacus</b>: Αἰακίδης, -ου, ὁ.
}}
```

Above and below could be other templates, with varying number of line breaks I.e.

```
{{MyTemplatename
|Text=text, text, text
}}
{{WoodhouseENELnames
|Text=text, text, text
}}
{{OtherTemplatename
|Text= text, text, text
}}
```

There are varying number of lines and/or line breaks within the template. I want to match the full template and delete it; that is match from `{{WoodhouseENELnames` to the closing `}}` but without matching any templates further down, that is, stop matching if further `{{` are encountered.

The closest I got was using something like:

Find
`({{WoodhouseENELnames\n\|Text=)(.*?)\n+(.*?)\n+(.*?)\n+(.*?)(\n+}})`

And adding/removing `(.*?)\n+` in the regex to match cases with more or less lines. The problem is that this expression might inadvertently match other templates following this one.

Is there a regex that would match all possible text/line breaks contained within the template (in a lazy way, as there may be other templates below and above) in the same page? The templates are delimited by opening `{{` and closing `}}`)?

Comment: Not sure if you're able to build a recursive regex with `mariadb` but if so, you could match all blocks with [`{{2}(?:[^{}]|(?R))+}{2}`](https://regex101.com/r/vjKlgC/1/) and only deletes those afterwards that start with `WoodhouseENELnames`. Without recursion, you'll surely need a parser instead.

Comment: I see, that indeed matches all blocks but how can there be a replace expression to delete that specific template only?

Comment: Imo, you'd be better off doing this programmatically then with regular expressions alone.

Comment: Indeed, Jan is right. I studied the exact same problem many years ago and came to the conclusion that their is no pure regex solution to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edited to clear up any confusing*

---

This is a recursion simulation for use on
***Java, Python style*** engines that do not support function calls (recursion)

`(?s)(?={{WoodhouseENELnames)(?:(?=.*?{{(?!.*?\1)(.*}}(?!.*\2).*))(?=.*?}}(?!.*?\2)(.*)).)+?.*?(?=\1)(?:(?!{{).)*(?=\2$)`

[Recursion Simulation demo](https://regex101.com/r/fYdNkt/1)

Just check matchs for result

---

This is real recursion for use on ***Perl, PCRE style*** engines

`(?s){{WoodhouseENELnames((?:(?>(?:(?!{{|}}).)+)|{{(?1)}})*)}}`

[Recursion demo](https://regex101.com/r/lR3pPX/1)

---

Note that Dot-Net is done differently and is not included here

Comment: It also matches other templates below that (same as in Jan's comment)

Comment: Even with the updated version, it will continue matching templates with other names below.

Comment: `(?={{WoodhouseENELnames\b)` is first text in regex. Assertion says don't match any name that not `WoodhouseENELnames`. Tis way assertions work. Yes ? Tis a well known fact, yes ?

Comment: `(?={{WoodhouseENELnames\b)(?:(?=.*?{{(?!.*?\1)(.*}}(?!.*\2).*))(?=.*?}}(?!.*?\2)(.*)).)+?.*?(?=\1)(?:(?!{{).)*(?=\2$)` returns no matches

Comment: Give the sample data  and regex usage for `(?s)(?={{WoodhouseENELnames)(?:(?=.*?{{(?!.*?\1)(.*}}(?!.*\2).*))(?=.*?}}(?!.*?\2)(.*)).)+?.*?(?=\1)(?:(?!{{).)*(?=\2$)` where dot matches all is set

Comment: What regex engine are you using? PCRE/Php, Perl, Python, R, other macro language ? I don't think this will work under JS but not sure.

Comment: The demo regex101 link provided uses the PCRE/Php engine. If that's what your language uses PCRE, it most definitely works. The dot all flag must be set. This demo uses inline flag `(?s)`

Comment: The query is run via Mediawiki interface using MariaDB as mentioned in first post. Data is the same as first post, you can copy and paste above and below templates with different template names to check.

Comment: Whats not matching, what is ? This is regex in answer `(?s)(?={{WoodhouseENELnames)(?:(?=.*?{{(?!.*?\1)(.*}}(?!.*\2).*))(?=.*?}}(?!.*?\2)(.*)).)+?.*?(?=\1)(?:(?!{{).)*(?=\2$)` this is regex demo using both your text sample top and bottom data with and without specified tag. [PCRE test demo](https://regex101.com/r/RZd3Fq/1). No problems here. yes ?

Comment: I've added a PCRE recursive regex to help broadly cover whatever your database supports.

Comment: I have made a few tests with `(?s){{WoodhouseENELnames((?:(?>(?:(?!{{|}}).)+)|{{(?1)}})*)}}` and it seems to work as requested.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of a brute-force, iterative approach using a recursive query.

The idea is to walk through the string, starting at the first occurence of string part `'{{WoodhouseENELnames'`. From there on, we can set a counter that keeps tracks of how many opening and closing brackets were met. When the count reaches `0`, we know the pattern is exhausted. The final step is to rebuild a string that retains the parts prior to and after the pattern.

For this to work, you need a unique column to identify each row. I assumed `id`.

```
with recursive cte as (
    select 
        n_open n0,
        n_open n1,
        1 cnt,
        mycol,
        id
    from (select t.*, locate('{{WoodhouseENELnames', mycol) n_open from mytable t) x
    where n_open > 0
    union all 
    select 
        n0,
        n1 + 2 + case when n_open > 0 and n_open < n_close then n_open else n_close end,
        cnt + case when n_open > 0 and n_open < n_close then 1 else -1 end,
        mycol,
        id
    from (
        select 
            c.*,
            locate('{{', substring(mycol, n1 + 2)) n_open,
            locate('}}', substring(mycol, n1 + 2)) n_close
        from cte c
    ) x
    where cnt > 0
)
select id, concat(substring(mycol, 1, min(n0) - 1), substring(mycol, max(n1) + 1)) mycol
from cte
group by id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=86b9ff568b7cc0239d8ecdd981413a7c)**

Set-up - I added string parts before and after the pattern (including double brackets for extra fun):

```
create table mytable(id int, mycol varchar(2000));
insert into mytable values (
    1,
    '{{abcd{{WoodhouseENELnames
|Text=[[File:woodhouse_999.jpg|thumb|link={{filepath:woodhouse_999.jpg}}]]Αἰακός, ὁ, or say, son of Aegina.

<b class="b2">Of Aeacus</b>, adj.: Αἰάκειος.

<b class="b2">Descendant of Aeacus</b>: Αἰακίδης, -ου, ὁ.
}} efgh{{'
);
```

Results:

```
id | mycol        
-: | :------------
 1 | {{abcd efgh{{
```

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB uses the PCRE-Regex engine.

If you can assure, that

1. the opening tag of your template (`{{WoodhouseENELnames`) starts on a new line
2. the closing tag of your template (`}}`) starts on a new line
3. no other closing tags (`}}`) in between starts on a new line, the follwoing Regex will do:

```
(?ms)^{{WoodhouseENELnames.+?^}}
```

Description:

1. `(?ms)` thells the regex that `^` matches any linebreak in the text and that `.` also matches newlines.
2. Then serach for your opening tag on a new line.
3. Search for the shortest possible string including any character (also newlines) up to
4. a closing tag (`}}`) on a new line.

If you want to capture the match, enclose the regex within `(`and `)`

EDIT:

As The PCRE2 supports recursive patterns, the follwing, more complexe regex will match, regardless of the beginnig-of-line-constraints above:

```
(?msx)
({{WoodhouseENELnames       # group 1: Matching the whole template
    (                       # group 2: Mathing the contents of the Template, including subpatters.
        [^{}]*              # Search zewro or more characters except { or }
        {{                  # The beginning of a subpattern
        (                   # Containg if:
            [^{}]++         # Search zewro or more characters except { or }
        |   (?2)            # or the recursive pattern group 2
        )*                  # Zero or more times
        }}                  # The closing of the subpattern.
        [^{}]*              # Search zewro or more characters except { or }
    )
    }}
)
```

Cave-at: Doesn't cater for single `{` or `}` within the templates.

EDIT 2

I hate giving up before the job is done :-) This regex should work regardless of all contstraints above:

```
(?msx)                  # Note the additional 'x'-Option, allowing free spacing.
({{WoodhouseENELnames   # Searcdh group 1 - Top level template:
    (                   #  Search group 2 - top level template contents:
        (               #   Search-group 3 - Subtemplate contents:
            [^{}]*      #    Zero or more characters except { or }
        |   {(?!{)      #    or a single { not follwed by a {
        |   }(?!})      #    or a single } not follwed by a }
        )*              #   Closing search group 3
        {{              #  Opening subtemplate tag
        (               #  Search group 4:
            (?3)*       #   Reusing serach group 3, zero or more times
        |   (?2)        #   or Recurse search group 2 (of which, this is a part)
        )*              #  Group 4 zero or more times
        }}              #  Closing subtemplate tag
        (?3)*           #  Reusing search group 3, zero or more times
    )                   #  Closing Search group 2 - Template contents
    }}                  #  Top-level Template closing tag
)                       # Closing Search group 1
```

The last two solutions are based on the [PCRE2 documentation](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#SEC25)

Comment: The first solution matched all templates in page (irrespective of template name, so not what we want), the 2nd and 3nd one `(?msx)({{WoodhouseENELnames(([^{}]*|{(?!{)|}(?!}))*{{((?3)*|(?2))*}}(?3)*)}})` (the 3rd went on and on for 10 mins), matched only a fraction of the pages containing this template, but correctly. I am guessing they missed some longer templates with multiple line breaks.

Comment: I can see that MariaDB 10.3 supports PCRE but not PCRE2 which is supported from 10.5 https://mariadb.com/kb/en/meta/pcre-versions/